# In an attempt to containerize WebdriverIO tests , I am getting the following error :webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

Tags: docker, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am using jasmine framework. I have a dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml in addition to a docker.conf.js. Selenium Grid hub is running fine but driver are not able to connect to it.

```
FROM node:12

RUN mkdir tests

COPY ./ /tests

WORKDIR /tests

VOLUME /tests/allure-report

RUN npm install --silent
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  wdio:
    build: .
    command: npm test docker.conf.js
    depends_on:
     - chrome
     - firefox
    links: 
      - hub
    environment: 
      -HUB_HOST: hub

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox 
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "5901:5900"

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

and my docker.conf.js has the following included:

```
port: 4444,
path: '/wd/hub',
host: 'hub',
protocol: 'http',
capabilities: [{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  maxInstances: 1
   }, {
       browserName: 'firefox',
       maxInstances: 1
   }],
```

Comment: Could you fix this?